# Project configuration problem: ASP.NET project without the option to add C # class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am creating an application with DDD architecture, where in the presentation layer I have an `ASP.NET` project. When I try to add a `C#` class to a folder in that layer, I can't find the `C#` class option, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I tried to create a `C#` class by selecting the Visual Basic class option, however when building it presents an error. Other procedures I tried:

- Add the Microsoft.CSharp package to your references;
- Download `C#` package with nuget.

However, I did not succeed with any attempt. What else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you chose VB when you created the project.

Comment: Is there any way to change this?

Comment: or you can create c# project and reference it from VB project

Comment: If you collapse VB option in the dialog, there should be c# option available. If not then you need to run the VS studio installer and select C# installation to install C# developer environment.